# How to get single-side box-shadow to appear from edge-to-edge?

Tags: html, css

For an element with 100% width and `box-shadow` defined such that it appears on the bottom only, how can I make the shadow appear consistent along the entire width of the element?

Currently, the shadow fades out at both the left and right edges; the shadow is noticeably different there than at the middle. Example:

```
<style>
body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
h1 { margin: 0; box-shadow: 0 10px 10px #009;}
</style>

<h1>Bacon</h1>
```

Or see http://jsfiddle.net/RxVbt/1/.

Comment: +1 for cured-meat pseudotext in the fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a spread distance to counter the blur value. For a blur of 10px you need a spread of 5px (5px in each direction = 10px) For example:

```
 h1 { margin: 0; box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 5px #009;}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/RxVbt/9/

Answer (score 3):

I did this by changing the h1 to include

```
margin-left: -10px; margin-right: -10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;
```

The negative margin pulls the shadow wide enough to appear the same all the way across. This is a bit crude and hackish, but it works.

Comment: Thank you, I have spent a lot of time tinkering with box shadows. They're my favorite new css feature by far.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
    `h1 { margin: 0; box-shadow: 0px 10px #009;}`

Comment: By removing the spread, all the fuzziness of the shadow is gone, and it looks just like a solid bottom border.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
h1 { margin: 0; box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 8px #009;}
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RxVbt/41/)

Comment: This is close, but the shadow turns out a bit thinner. What's happening in this example?

Comment: i increased the blur from 5px to 8px so the shadow shouldn't be so thin. i edited my answer with example also.

Answer (score 0):

Add negative values for the end caps.

`box-shadow: -5px -5px 10px 10px #009;`

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/RxVbt/19/)